# как создать непрерывную бегущую строку?

Tags: javascript

как создать непрерывную бегущую строку?

Comment: вот один из способов - преобразуйте текст в текстуру,  натяните ее на цилиндр, вращайте цилиндр в webGL.

Comment: @zb' по-моему извращение

Comment: @Alex78191 и тотКтоПлюсанул -- ***лопата***. Извращение давать ответы на общие вопросы.

Comment: @zb' Уж лучше либу использовать

Comment: Кстати по ответам, не вижу непрерывности в обоих :) вы, ребята, бегущую строку видели когда нибудь ? короче - создаем два блока шириной 100% или больше,  в них дублируем (к сожалению по другому не сработает) то что собираемся бежать, сдвигаем на 100% (имеем ввиду ширину блока текста, если он больше ширины контейнера), в нужную сторону с транзишеном, потом без транзишена сдвигаем обратно, и тд. Иначе (без дублирования) - сдвиг битмапа (почти то что я написал сверху_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно использовать плагин jQuery.Marquee.

- duplicated – задает непрерывность текста.
- startVisible – текст должен
  заполнять пространство при начале.
- duration – задает время, за
  которое текст должен прокрутиться.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.marquee').marquee({
    duration: 7000,
    startVisible: true,
    duplicated: true
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.marquee/1.4.0/jquery.marquee.min.js"></script>

<div class='marquee' style='overflow:hidden'>jQuery plugin to scroll the text like the old traditional marquee. A 5.51 KB (minified) jQuery plugin to scroll the text like the old traditional marquee.</div>
```

Comment: Сколько раз пользовался этим плагином работает всегда криво , нормально работает только с текстом , если докинуть туда дивов или картинки начинает криво работать, с помощью флексов нужно править

Answer (score 9):

используйте тег `Marquee`, но учтите он устарел. Но до сих пор работает.

```html
<marquee direction="right" scrollamount="10">Бегущая строка</marquee>
```

Comment: Как на javascript?

Comment: Забавно, что при поиске в гугле [marquee html](https://www.google.ru/search?q=marquee+html) отображается бегущая строка.

Comment: Ух-ты, прикольно ;)

Answer (score 7):

Бегущую строку можно также реализовать с помощью css

Пример

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.b-marquee {
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.b-marquee__text {
  -webkit-animation: animMarquee 5s linear infinite;
  animation: animMarquee 5s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes animMarquee {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

@keyframes animMarquee {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}


/* text right to left*/

.b-marquee--rtl {}

.b-marquee--rtl .b-marquee__text {
  -webkit-animation: animMarqueeRtl 5s linear infinite;
  animation: animMarqueeRtl 5s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes animMarqueeRtl {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
}

@keyframes animMarqueeRtl {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="b-marquee">
  <div class="b-marquee__text">Text left to right</div>
</div>
<div class="b-marquee b-marquee--rtl">
  <div class="b-marquee__text">Text right to left</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `-webkit` можно не писать

Comment: @Qwertiy стоит для Android 4 версии, а 5 и выше уже без преффикса -webkit- работает

Comment: Почему стоит тег javascript, а решение на CSS?

Comment: @Alex78191 - это всего лишь один из вариантов решения, + автор вопроса может быть не в курсе, что данную задачу возможно решить с помощью css

Answer (score 4):

Если хочется на JS, то пожалуйста :-)

```js
var wrapper = document.querySelector('.marquee-wrapper'),
    marquee = document.querySelector('.marquee'),   
    wrapperWidth = wrapper.offsetWidth,
    marqueeWidth = marquee.scrollWidth;
    
document.querySelector('button').onclick = function() {
  clearInterval(interval)
}
    
function move() {
  var currentTX = getComputedStyle(marquee).transform.split(',');
  if( currentTX[4] === undefined ) {
    currentTX = -1;
  } else {
    currentTX = parseFloat(currentTX[4]) - 1;
  }
  
  if(-currentTX >= marqueeWidth) {
    marquee.style.transform = 'translateX(' + wrapperWidth + 'px)';
  
  } else {
    marquee.style.transform = 'translateX(' + currentTX + 'px)';
  }
}

var interval = setInterval(move, 40);
```

```css
.marquee-wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.marquee-wrapper:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: ' ';
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, transparent, #fff);
}

.marquee {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class=marquee-wrapper>
  <p class=marquee>это бегущая строка, которая реализована при помощи яваскрипта, хотя можно было бы и без него</p>
</div>

<button>stop</button>
```

Comment: Она не непрерывная.

Comment: 1. сразу добавить `.marquee` `translateX(100%)`

Comment: 2. добавить обработчики `onmouseover` (точно так же обнулять интервал, как сейчас для клика по кнопке) и `onmouseout`(точно так же запускать интервал, как сейчас в конце кода)