# Бегущая строка без использования тега <marquee>

Tags: javascript, css

Как можно создать бегущую строку на javascript? Текст, который надо показывать предварительно вводится пользователем и потому может быть любой длины.

Пока у меня имеется следующий костяк:

```js
window.onload = function() {

  document.getElementById("button").onclick = function() {

    var value = document.getElementById("input").value;

    // код, который нужно дописать

  };
};
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="input">Введите строку</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="input">
  <input type="button" id="button" value="Жми!">
</form>
```

Comment: Это база знаний, а не форум. Не надо удалять вопрос после получения на него ответа. Он полезен не только вам, но и всем будущим посетителям с подобной проблемой.

Comment: Если есть возможность использовать JQuery, то [вам подойдёт плагин jQuery.Marquee](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/668893/208074).

Comment: Есть [ещё одно решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/668911/208074), которое вы можете доработать под свои нужды.

Comment: Просмотрел историю правок, оказывается такие бури пронеслись,- закрывали, открывали, закрывали, открывали.  @KvinT в бане. Что можно сказать начинающему задавать вопросы,- Знаете, что было написано на кольце царя Соломона: "Всё проходит, и это пройдёт" Может с этой точки зрения вам будет спокойнее и не будете обижаться, удалять посты, со временем поймёте и примите правила игры.

Answer (score 9):

```js
document.getElementById("button").onclick = function() {
  var value = document.getElementById("input").value;
  document.getElementById('marquee').innerHTML = '<span>'+ value +'</span>';
};
```

```css
#marquee {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 50px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    color: red;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#marquee span {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 100%;
    animation: marquee 15s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes marquee {
    0%   { transform: translate(-100%, 0); }
    100% { transform: translate(0, 0); }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="input">Введите строку:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="input">
  <input type="button" id="button" value="Жми!">
</form>
<div id="marquee"></div>
```

Comment: На [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee) написано, что лучше не использовать `<marquee>`

Comment: Вопрошающий написал же, что надо без `<marquee>`.

Comment: @Arhad, если вы не заметили, то я ответ написал на день раньше, чем автор изменил свое сообщение.

Comment: @diraria, обновил ответ

Comment: @diraria, и нет метки css.

Answer (score 3):

Когда вводим, сначала строка печатается в поле, а после начинает туда-сюда бегать.

```js
var line = '', 
speedPrint = 200, 
speedTicker = 20, 
i = 0, 
l = 0, 
back = false, 
ticker = document.getElementById('ticker'), 
input = document.getElementById('text'), 
end = function () {
    w = document.body.clientWidth;
    ticker.style.position = 'relative';
    if (!back && l < w) {
        l += 5;
        ticker.style.left = l + 'px';
    } else {
        if (0 === l || 0 > l) {
            l = 0;
            back = false;
            ticker.style.left = '0px';
        } else {
            back = true;
            l -= 5;
            ticker.style.left = l + 'px';
        }
    }
    setTimeout(end, speedTicker);
}, 
text = function () {
    if (!(line = input.value)) {
        input.focus();
        return;
    }
    setTimeout(run, 200);
}, 
run = function () {
    if (i < line.length) {
        i++;
        ticker.innerText = line.substring(0, i);
        setTimeout(run, speedPrint);
    } else {
        end();
    }
};
```

```html
<span id="ticker"></span>
<hr>
<input name="text" type="text" id="text">
<a href="javascript:text()">
   Побежали
</a>
```

Comment: мне понравились оба ответа, но ваш больше. (+)

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, спасибо, правда его нужно до ума доводить под свои нужны.

Comment: добавил метку css